# growth of 11 million vs an 11 million growth

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I want to know whether ***a/an X million growth*** is the same as ***a growth of X million***.

> The year 2001 witnessed **a growth of 11 million** in the number of households that live in a rented accommodation.

> The year 2001 witnessed **an 11 million growth** in the number of households that live in a rented accommodation.

I want to say that a number grew by 11 million.

Comment: You need to give a sentence as an example of how you will use the phrase. You also might wish to consider posting this on the English Language Learners site.

Comment: @Greybeard I can't find the website you mentioned.

Comment: The second version is *terrible*, but at the very least I would remove ***both*** indefinite articles in the first one. Personally, I think ***...witnessed growth of 11 million*** is a bit "flowery" for this exact context anyway - it would be much better expressed as ***...grew by 11 million*** (which is *exactly* what you quite naturally wrote when telling us what you want to say! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference would be to use "saw" and "increase", for example (a) …***saw an increase of 11 million***… or (b) *The number of rented accommodation **increased by 11 million** in 2021*.

If the OP wants to preserve the sense of *growth*, why not use it as a verb?

> The year 2021 **saw** the number of rented accommodation **grow** from XXX million to XXX million.

> The number of households in rented accommodation **grew by** 11 million in 2021

The phrase "a 11 million growth" is not idiomatic, and some might argue ungrammatical. The phrase *eleven million growth* begins with a vowel sound, so the indefinite article ***an*** should precede it.
E.g “An 11 million-dollar NYC apartment”

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring adjectives, the slot in 'a ...... growth' is almost always filled by a scale factor expressed as a percentage, like **300%**, or equivalent like **threefold** – not as a numeral or equivalent (300, a dozen). And 'increase' would be the more normal noun to use. But sticking with 'growth': while 'a growth of 100' is reasonably idiomatic usage, the Google ngram for 'a 100 growth' is a flatline:

[image]

Correspondingly, the ratio of Google hits in searches for and "a growth of 5000" and  ["a 5000 growth" -"A ="] (the filter to avoid a major false positive) is about 140 000 : 0.

On the other hand, 'a 100% growth' outperforms 'a growth of 100%', though both are quite acceptable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't like either usage, though the first is sort of grammatically correct.

Your word "witnessed" indicates some entity (person, group of people, something) that did the witnessing, and the indication that the number of renting households did the witnessing seems unlikely to be what you mean.

The phrase "witnessed an 11 million growth" is awkward; I don't know language rules that would tell you that it is awkward, unfortunately, but a native English speaker is unlikely to say that.

I agree with a comment you got that "The number ... grew by 11 million" would be simpler, clearer, easier to read, and has all the meaning you've indicated you want.

Comment: I tried to fix the "witnessed" part.